# Value Error upon normalisation: array must not contain infs or NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

I am trying to normalise my data using '`.apply(np.log10)`', but upon normalisation some of the rows turns to -inf. As I want to plot the distribution of the data after normalisation I was wondering if someone could help me with the following:
1- How to get rid of rows containing Nans or inf using Pandas?
2- An explanation of why this happens.

Comment: call `dropna` or `np.log10(df.dropna())` should work

Answer (score 2):

An `inf` generally happens because you divide by zero.  Because you are using logs, you get an `inf` if you take the log of zero.

You can remove all rows that contain NaNs and Infs as follows:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
df.iat[0, 0] /= 0  # Add an inf
df.iat[-1, -1] = np.nan  # Add a NaN

>>> df
          A         B         C
0       inf  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
4  0.761038  0.121675       NaN

>>> df[df.apply(np.isfinite).all(axis=1)]
          A         B         C
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
```